# Sync UI with backend when data keeps on changing at random interval by multiple users

Tags: database, node.js

I have Node-Express backend with REST API and no particular frontend technology as it will be based on different platforms and don't want to limit it.

On POST/PUT request, change is done in the database. A new element(array) may be created, updated or deleted.

Multiple users can update the information on that field and present value in a database should be shown to the user.

Currently, a request is made at a particular interval and the complete array is replaced with a newly fetched array. The problem with this approach begins when array size increases, a lot of unnecessary data is consumed and time is wasted. Many times there is no change in values but the same data is (fetched and) replaced from a database to UI which makes no sense. Also, change in a single item and replacement of complete array is a bad method.

What other methods can I implement so that my bandwidth is conserved and time taken is lesser?